# SQLAlchemy error MySQL server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask

Error `OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')` i'm already received this error when i coded project on Flask, but i cant understand why i get this error.

I have code (yeah, if code small and executing fast, then no errors) like this \

```
db_engine = create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1/mind?charset=utf8', pool_size=10, pool_recycle=7200)
Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine, autoflush=True)
Session = scoped_session(Session)
session = Session()

# there many classes and functions

session.close()
```

And this code returns me error `'MySQL server has gone away'`, but return it after some time, when i use pauses in my script.

Mysql i use from openserver.ru (it's web server like such as wamp).

Thanks..

Comment: Documentation for [MySQL server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

Comment: i think, that i get this error because i have logic error in my script...

Comment: I think you have to re-create the engine or sessionmaker when this happens, but I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 30):

Looking at the mysql docs, we can see that there are a [bunch of reasons why this error can occur](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html).  However, the two main reasons I've seen are:

---

**1)** The most common reason is that the connection has been dropped because it hasn't been used in more than 8 hours (default setting)

> By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if nothing has happened. You can change the time limit by setting the wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld

I'll just mention for completeness the two ways to deal with that, but they've already been mentioned in other answers:

*A*: I have a very long running job and so my connection is stale.  To fix this, I refresh my connection:

```
create_engine(conn_str, pool_recycle=3600)  # recycle every hour
```

*B*: I have a long running service and long periods of inactivity.  To fix this I ping mysql before every call:

```
create_engine(conn_str, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

---

**2)** My packet size is too large, which should throw this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1153, "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes")
```

I've only seen this buried in the middle of the trace, though often you'll only see the generic `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`, so it's hard to catch, especially if logs are in multiple places.

[The above doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html) say the max packet size is 64MB by default, but it's actually 16MB, which can be verified with `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet`

To fix this, decrease packet size for `INSERT` or `UPDATE` calls.

Comment: other answer great also, but you telling about "why" and it's make more helpful rather than other answer,, thanks

Comment: Could you provide details on why 1.A and 1.B should be handled differently? Shouldn't it be enough  with the pool recycle for both?

Answer (score 20):

SQLAlchemy now has a great write-up on how you can use pinging to be pessimistic about your connection's freshness:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic

From there,

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool

@event.listens_for(Pool, "checkout")
def ping_connection(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT 1")
    except:
        # optional - dispose the whole pool
        # instead of invalidating one at a time
        # connection_proxy._pool.dispose()

        # raise DisconnectionError - pool will try
        # connecting again up to three times before raising.
        raise exc.DisconnectionError()
    cursor.close()
```

And a test to make sure the above works:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo_pool=True)
c1 = e.connect()
c2 = e.connect()
c3 = e.connect()
c1.close()
c2.close()
c3.close()

# pool size is now three.

print "Restart the server"
raw_input()

for i in xrange(10):
    c = e.connect()
    print c.execute("select 1").fetchall()
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

from [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) you can use `pool_recycle` parameter:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", pool_recycle=3600)
```

Comment: The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16341911/110488) is already using this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same problem, which is solved with some effort. Wish my experience be helpful to others.

Fallowing some suggestions, I used connection pool and set `pool_recycle` less than `wait_timeout`, but it still doesn't work.

Then, I realized that global session maybe just use the same connection and connection pool didn't work. To avoid global session, for each request generate a new session which is removed by `Session.remove()` after processing.

Finally, all is well.

Answer (score 0):

One more point to keep in mind is to manually push the flask application context with database initialization. This should resolve the issue.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
```

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-optimistic

```
 def sql_read(cls, sql, connection):
    """sql for read action like select
    """
    LOG.debug(sql)
    try:
        result = connection.engine.execute(sql)
        header = result.keys()
        for row in result:
            yield dict(zip(header, row))
    except OperationalError as e:
        LOG.info("recreate pool duo to %s" % e)
        connection.engine.pool.recreate()
        result = connection.engine.execute(sql)
        header = result.keys()
        for row in result:
            yield dict(zip(header, row))
    except Exception as ee:
        LOG.error(ee)
        raise SqlExecuteError()
```